# For loop not working in python with csv file

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

I am writing a script in python to read a .csv file and print it on the basis of row.I am not getting any error while executing, but it doesn't get printed.
The code is as follows.

```
import os
import csv

os.chdir('C:\ingenium')

exampleFile = open('testt.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
for row in exampleReader:
    print (row)
exampleFile.close()
```

Later I have found out that the word "row" doesnt have any significance in code as I replace "row" by any random string (for eg:"gcgc") it doesnt show any error.
.
I am using Pycharm as IDE.

Comment: for row in exampleReader --> you do not use exampleData

Comment: So just remove the line `exampleData = list(exampleReader)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

import csv

os.chdir('C:\ingenium')

exampleFile = open('testt.csv','r')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
for row in exampleReader:
    print (row)
exampleFile.close()
```

As moses said, you already exhausted the csv.reader by importing the csv to list.

Answer (score 4):

Your bug is here:

```
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
```

You already exhausted the generator object `exampleReader`, so you don't get anything when you iterate over it.

You should iterate over the new list instead:

```
for row in exampleData:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the specific task, printing the lines, it might be worth playing with simpler file handling.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\ingenium')

lines = open('testt.csv','r').readlines()
for line in lines:
    print (line)
```

Comment: Even if your solution works the OP is asking why they solution not work. Could you shed some light on that?

Comment: Sure!  Think of an iterator as the arm on a turntable.  It starts at the outside (first track) and works it's way thru to the center (end of the album).  When it gets there, it's **done**.  When his code begins the for loop, the 'reader' is empty (finished).

Comment: Also, that for loop would have explained itself to the OP if he added one more print statement, something like:

    for row in example reader:
        print '- ', row